# django_content_type error in django seo2

Tags: python, django, github, seo, travis-ci

I am working on a Django(1.8) project.
I am trying to implement [django-seo2](https://github.com/romansalin/django-seo2).

Integrated Travis CI on GitHub for continuous integration.
I keep getting the following error on Travis:

```
ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
```

On my local machine:

```
python manage.py showmigrations

account
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_email_max_length
admin
 [ ] 0001_initial
auth
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [ ] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [ ] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [ ] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [ ] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
authtoken
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_auto_20160226_1747
contenttypes
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_remove_content_type_name
payment
 [ ] 0001_initial
profiles
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_auto_20160610_1309
sessions
 [ ] 0001_initial
sites
 [ ] 0001_initial
socialaccount
 [ ] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_token_max_lengths
 [ ] 0003_extra_data_default_dict
webpages
 (no migrations)
```

If I migrate before implementing django-seo2 and then I migrate after implementing django-seo2 no error occurs.

But if new database is used and after implementing django-seo2, I try python manage.py migrate , the same error occurs:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version on pypi is 12 commits behind master.
I solved the problem by installing the django-seo2 directly from its source on [github](https://github.com/romansalin/django-seo2)

I created an [issue](https://github.com/romansalin/django-seo2/issues/20) for update in django-seo2 Python Package Index, but I think the github repository is not maintained by the owner now.